# php update not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change a form data and updating the data in mysql. But the data is not changing when ever I am trying to update. The form page is below:

```
while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $reqitem=$list5['id'];
    echo "<td width='34%' id='addinput'><input type='text' size='70' id='item_name$i' 
name='item_name[$i]' placeholder='{$list5['prod_description']}' 
value='{$list5['prod_description']}'></td>";
}
```

And the save page script is as follows:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key=>$value)
{
    $item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];
   $q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items prod_description='$item_name' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$value' ";
    mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I know there is a problem with script. I am very new to php so not able to grasp where I am making mistake. Can anyone please help me on this.

Following is the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
    <form action='generate_quot_cust_edititems_save_1.php?tender_id=1400692'
    class='single' id="cart" method='post' name='cart'>

        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
             <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>154<input id='item_name0'
                        name='item_name[0]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>155<input id='item_name1'
                        name='item_name[1]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>156<input id='item_name2'
                        name='item_name[2]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
                 <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>157<input id='item_name3'
                        name='item_name[3]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>158<input id='item_name4'
                        name='item_name[4]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>159<input id='item_name5'
                        name='item_name[5]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="base">
            <div align="left">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style=
                "border-collapse: collapse;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td id='addinput' width='34%'>160<input id='item_name6'
                        name='item_name[6]' placeholder='Packing Charges.'
                        size='70' type='text' value='Packing Charges.'></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div><br>
<input type='submit' value='--Update Data--' id='continue'/>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **1**. Don't use the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions. They are deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. **2**. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your query (works if you use MySQLi or PDO).

Comment: Can you post the HTML over to the Question since it would be useful to figure out the Error that you made..

Comment: USE `SET` like below 

`$q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items SET prod_description='$item_name' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$value' ";` 

I also recommend not you use mysql_*. Use mysqli OR PDO. These are recommended for PHP 7 and also have so much benefits for using mysqli like 

- Object-oriented interface,
- Support for Prepared Statements, 
- Support for Multiple Statements,  
- Support for Transactions, 
- Enhanced debugging capabilities, 
- Embedded server support

Comment: I will keep that in mind, but iam just trying to edit an existing code which is written a bit while ago.

Comment: @ Naresh, i have put the html code for your reference

Comment: Ya but there is no submit button in your form @SanjuMenon. Then how will it be posted

Comment: i missed that when copying it. Added the submitted button

Comment: The switch from mysql_ to mysqli_ (and prepared statements) requires relatively little adjustment to your code, so there's really no excuse not to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following bit in your `save.php` looks fishy:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key=>$value)
{
    //$item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];
   $q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items set prod_description='$value' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$key' ";
    mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

shouldn't you be looping over  `$_POST['item_name']` ? something like:

```
foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $key=>$value)
{

    $item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];
   $q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items set prod_description='$value' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$key' ";
    mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

If that's the case you might even consider to change your form page logic as follows:

```
while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $reqitem=$list5['id'];
    echo "<td width='34%' id='addinput'><input type='text' size='70' id='item_name$i' 
name='item_name[$reqitem]' placeholder='{$list5['prod_description']}' 
value='{$list5['prod_description']}'></td>";
}
```

Comment: This is where iam confused. I should loop over id or item name?

Comment: And which is the FOR LOOP i need to use which u suggested?

Comment: you should be using `foreach($_POST['item_name'] as $key=>$value)` mentioned in the code

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the `set` clause:

```
  $q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items set prod_description='$item_name' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$value' ";
```

Hint: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` with prepared Statements. `mysql_*`will be removed in the next Version of php and prepared Statements prevent you against SQL injection.

Comment: i just updated the script with SET but there is a problem. There was some 6 rows in the form. When i clicked submit button , it updated the last row value to all the other 6 rows.

Comment: May be the id and data iam not passing properly to the save page?

Comment: maybe. echoing the Statement and see how it Looks like

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below line

```
$q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items prod_description='$item_name' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$value' ";
```

to

```
$q = "UPDATE poto_customer_items SET prod_description='$item_name' WHERE tender_id='$tender_id' and id='$value' ";
```

Comment: i just updated the script with SET but there is a problem. There was some 6 rows in the form. When i clicked submit button , it updated the last row value to all the other 6 rows.

Comment: I am not getting your point friend can you please explain what you want to say ?

Comment: I have added the html part to my question. Its just a simple form with item names. There are 6 rows. So the user updates the item name and submits it and it should change in the mysql db. That's the actual requirement.

Comment: Might be foreach($_POST['id'] as $key=>$value) this will gives you only one row.